# Magento2.2.4: The top menu not showing to the product detail page

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2.4

**I'm getting issue with the Top Menu on PDP page:**

I have upgraded my magento website 2.1.7 to 2.2.4. I got two issues:

1. Breadcrumbs issue ( Breadcrumbs not display on PDP page )
2. Top menu issue  ( Top menu not display on PDP page )

**I have fixed the breadcrumb issue by following below link:**
https://github.com/VOREStation/VOREStation/issues/3751

But not found any solution for the top menu issue. I have checked my all custom modules there is no remove attribute used for removing the top menu & no other static conditions.

If anyone knows the solution then please let me know.

On home page the top menu is showing but on PDP page it is not showing. We have removed the top menu only for checkout & cart page.

Here is the website URL:

https://www.firefold.com/

PDP page URL:

https://www.firefold.com/digital-clamp-meter-klein-tools-cl600

Comment: If you try to save the theme via schedule update inside product details in admin, then the header menu comes?

Comment: Check your product page XML maybe nav section remove from XML.

Comment: try cache disable after check working or not working

Comment: Thanks Prashant Patel. Yes, the issue with the FPC cache. But why the FPC effects only on PDP page ?